# Bootstrap modal - backdrop stays when I use the back button from the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I display an error message to the user, I use the following script to open a modal message:

```
jQuery('#errorDialog').modal({
    keyboard: false,
    show: true,
    backdrop: 'static'
});
```

It works very well and displays the message as I wanted to.

The problem is that when I use the back button from the browser, it takes me to the previous page in the history (all good) but the backdrop is still on the screen.

I tried to remove the `backdrop: 'static'` line which had the effect of dismissing the modal message when I clicked the anywhere on the backdrop. Nevertheless, it still stays when going back the the previous page.

Is there a way to remove it when I use the back button (or navigate through browser history otherwise)?

Comment: are you using some sort of pushstate?

Comment: Not that I know of. This code was written by someone else and handed over to me so I haven't figured out everything yet though...

Comment: It's very likely that this is not a bug in jQuery or misconfiguration but the rest of the code.

Comment: Are you using backbone or a similar single page application framework?

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with a SPA javascript framework like for example Vue, React or Angular, is normal that when there is a back button pressed, the bootstrap or jQuery UI backdrop stays visible.

The reason is because the backdrop div is inserted usually at the top of the DOM and when back is pressed, it just re-renders the Node more down in the DOM.

The solution is for example, detect every history change and execute:

```
$(".modal-backdrop").remove()
```

In the case of Vue for example, it can be done in the vue-router like so:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
  next();
});
```

Comment: I have this issue in react, can you tell me how to fix it in react?

Comment: Thank you, this works. But don't you think this would affect the app's performance overall since it would run every time the route changes.

Comment: If you are not using jQuery. you can simply:
document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0] ? document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0].remove() : '';

Comment: @Vaibhawkr In React I used it: const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0]) {
            document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0].remove();
        }
    }, [location]);

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem using backbone.js.  For anyone else experiencing this issue.  Here's my hack to fix it.

I have a function in myRouter that loads my views on route change.

```
loadView: function(view) {

    var _this = this;

    if (_this.currentView) {
        _this.currentView.close();
    }

    _this.currentView = view;
    _this.currentView.render();

    // Render view to dom
    $(".content").html(_this.currentView.el);

    // Set opacity of modal backdrop to 0
    $('.modal-backdrop').css('opacity', 0);

} //,
```

Then on route change you just call loadView like this:

```
index: function() {

    _this.loadView(new IndexView());

} //,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I moved on from this project but I'll try review your answer later.